# Blazor JSRuntime problem when importing javascript file in component and using on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, blazor

I have a modal component that uses a .js file to run. In order to attach the JavaScript I make a call in `OnAfterRenderAsync` function.

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var libraryName = GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name;
            await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", $"./_content/{libraryName}/scripts/aria.modal.min.js");
        }
    }
```

And this works fine when I place this component on certain page.
But, when I have this same component called on different page and navigate from one to another the script fails to load without any error and the modal won't open unless I reload the page.

I tried calling simple .js file that has only one line of code `alert("bla");`, and the same thing happened. It works on the first time I navigate to the page, and then when I navigate to the other page with the same component the script fails without any error.

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<div id="@Id" data-modal data-modal-manual-close hidden class="c-modal @Id-modal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div data-modal-document role="document">

        @if (!hasBody)
        {
            <h2 class="c-modal__title @Id-modal__head" id="tableLabel">
                @HeaderContent
            </h2>
            <div class="c-modal__body @Id-modal__body">
                @BodyContent
            </div>

            <footer class="c-modal__footer @Id-modal__footer">
                <button class="btn btn--primary">Select</button>
                <button data-modal-close-btn class="btn btn--outline">Cancel</button>
            </footer>

            <button data-modal-close-btn aria-labelledby="close-button-label" class="btn c-modal__close-btn">
                <span id="close-button-label" hidden>Close</span>
                <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
                    <path d="M18.4652 8.15127L13.6165 13L18.4652 17.8487L16.849 19.465L12.0002 14.6162L7.1515 19.465L5.53526 17.8487L10.384 13L5.53526 8.15127L7.1515 6.53502L12.0002 11.3838L16.849 6.53502L18.4652 8.15127Z" fill="currentColor" />
                </svg>
            </button>
        }
        else
        {
            @BodyContent
        }
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public bool hasBody { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment BodyContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment HeaderContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Id { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var libraryName = GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name;
            await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", $"./_content/{libraryName}/scripts/aria.modal.min.js");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement a *Dispose* in your razor page.
Like:

```
...
@implements IAsyncDisposable
...
@code {
    private IJSObjectReference module;
...
            module = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", $"./_content/{libraryName}/scripts/aria.modal.min.js");
...
async ValueTask IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (module is not null)
        {
            await module.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I already tried this. It does not solve the problem.